# Splide js + React how to specify certain slide by clicking static thumbnails using '.go()' methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, splidejs

I am coding with React (FC not class) and Splide js to make carousel and thumbnails. Thumbnails should not be a carousel, should be static and like bottons.

I read the [official document](https://splidejs.com/tutorials/gallery/) and could not redo on React. I am using 'useRef' hook but I don't know how to connect with `.go()` function. Here is my code:

**Hero.tsx**

```
import { Splide, SplideSlide } from '@splidejs/react-splide';
import { Options } from '@splidejs/splide';

import '@splidejs/react-splide/css';

import './Hero.scss';

import p1 from '../assets/image-product-1.jpg';
import p2 from '../assets/image-product-2.jpg';
import p3 from '../assets/image-product-3.jpg';
import p4 from '../assets/image-product-4.jpg';

import { useRef } from 'react';

export default function Hero() {
  const thumbsImages = [
    require('../assets/image-product-1-thumbnail.jpg'),
    require('../assets/image-product-2-thumbnail.jpg'),
    require('../assets/image-product-3-thumbnail.jpg'),
    require('../assets/image-product-4-thumbnail.jpg'),
  ];

  const mainOptions: Options = {
    type: 'loop',
    perPage: 1,
    perMove: 1,
    gap: '1rem',
    pagination: false,
    height: '27.8125rem',
  };

  const mainRef = useRef<Splide>(null);

  const handleThumbs = (id: number) => {
    mainRef.go(id);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Splide options={mainOptions} ref={mainRef}>
        <SplideSlide>
          <img src={p1} alt="product image 1" />
        </SplideSlide>
        <SplideSlide>
          <img src={p2} alt="product image 2" />
        </SplideSlide>
        <SplideSlide>
          <img src={p3} alt="product image 3" />
        </SplideSlide>
        <SplideSlide>
          <img src={p4} alt="product image 4" />
        </SplideSlide>
      </Splide>

      <ul className="thumbnails">
        {thumbsImages.map((thumbnail, index) => (
          <li>
            <button onClick={() => handleThumbs(index)}>
              <img src={thumbnail} alt="product thumbnail" />
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

TypeScript yells at me saying `Property 'go' does not exist on type 'RefObject<Splide>'.`.
I would like to fire the onClick function once I click each thumbnails and go to the specific slide that has the same index as the thumbnail.

I appreciate if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to call the `go()` function on the `ref.current` so your
handleThumb function

should be

```
const handleThumbs = (id: number) => {
  if (mainRef.current) {
     mainRef.current.go(id);
  }
};
```

Comment: I got this error by your solution and could not compile...  `Object is possibly 'null'.`

Comment: Hi, I solved by changing it to ```const handleThumbs = (id: number) => {
    if (mainRef.current) {
      mainRef.current.go(id);
    }
  }; ```  Thanks for help!